# Failed - No file

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, root, tomcat9

I am new in Tomcat Server as well in Java as I take over code from other developer. I attached pdf file in web pages to be download from footer section. The footer was from another directory inside webapps ROOT/WEB-INF/../../contactUs.jsp and the file is in webapps/brochure.pdf so I called the pdf file and it display into web page but when I download then it say **"Failed - No file"**

src:

```
<aside class="widget widget_footer"> 
    <h4 class="widget-title">Company</h4> 
    <ul class="ps-list--link"> 
     <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/about-us.jsp">About Us</a></li> 
     <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/careers.jsp">Career</a></li> 
     <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/common/viewcontactscreen/0">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/brochure.pdf" download>User Guide</a></li> 
    </ul> 
   </aside>
```

Thanks for corresponding my question in advance.

I want to the file to be downloadable for client.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The paths you mention look strange:

`ROOT/WEB-INF/../../contactUs.jsp` would mean `contactUs.jsp` is besides `ROOT`?
`webapps/brochure.pdf` would mean brochure.pdf is besides ROOT as well?

This is not where Tomcat would serve files, and your error message is likely related to that.

In the webapps directory you should have different web applications - each of them in either a directory or the zipped version, a `.war` file. `ROOT` is just a web application specially treated by Tomcat. Inside a webapp you can find content to be served directly, just like a htdocs directory on a webserver installation - or the special directory WEB-INF, which contains internal data not directly presented on the network.

So assuming your webapp's name is ROOT, place your pdf into the path `webapps/ROOT/brochure.pdf` and reference it as `/brochure.pdf` from JSP pages. Hint: it should reside in the same directory as `about-us.jsp`.